# Create executable gradle task

Tags: gradle, groovy

Currently, I have a task in gradle something like this

```
class MyTask  extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    public void run() {

    }
}
```

Something like this which I can do in build.gradle

```
task stopTomcat(type:Exec) {
  workingDir '../tomcat/bin'

  //on windows:
  commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'stop.bat'

  //on linux
  commandLine './stop.sh'

  //store the output instead of printing to the console:
  standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

  //extension method stopTomcat.output() can be used to obtain the output:
  ext.output = {
    return standardOutput.toString()
  }
}
```

I want to make this task executable accessing commandLine, workingDir etc. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean by executable? What do you mean by _" accessing commandLine, workingDir etc"_

Comment: @tim_yates. Added further info in the body of the question

Answer (score 0):

You can do this sort of thing (if that's what you mean):

```
class MyTask  extends DefaultTask {
    private workingDir
    private commandLine

    void workingDir(String workingDir) {
        this.workingDir = workingDir
    }

    void commandLine(String commandLine) {
        this.commandLine = commandLine
    }

    @TaskAction
    void run() {
        println "I will run $commandLine in $workingDir"
    }
}
```